# Why is my front door camera still working when it's static IP is from a different subnet?

Tags: subnet

Recently I put my AT&T router in passthrough mode to have more control over my network. My ATT router acts on `192.168.1.xxx` while my new TP-Link router IP is in the `192.168.0.xxx` range.

I have a few different devices that were set with a static IP in the `192.168.1.xxx` range like my Wi-Fi AP, my nas, and a few Docker images on the NAS, and finally I have an ip cam on my front door. I've got most of them reset into the new range except my front door cam, because that involves getting a ladder to press the reset button and I'm lazy.

I noticed this morning that I'm still getting email alerts from the camera though; It's hardwired through a POE switch to my main switch to the router, so it does have hardwired internet access, but per it's last configuration it's on a different subnet than the router doles out IP's for.

How is the camera connected to the internet? It doesn't have Wi-Fi, it could only be sending messages through the hardwired connection through the router, but the router shouldn't be paying attention to messages outside of it's network segment, right?

---

Just a bit more info, I don't see the IP in my router info pages, but I don't see other statically assigned IP's either (which bothers me a bit about this particular router TBH); I also don't see it in fing on my phone (but I do see static assigned devices in the `192.168.0.xxx` subnet)

Answer (score 1):

My main guess would be IPv6. You only mentioned IPv4 configuration; the TP-Link router most likely gets an IPv6 prefix from AT&T and the camera picks up an IPv6 address from it.

Performing a packet capture (either tcpdump on the router, or port mirroring on one of your switches + tcpdump/wireshark on a PC) would be one way to find out.

> the router shouldn't be paying attention to messages outside of it's network segment, right?

Technically it will — it pays attention to inbound packets from the entire Internet — it's the replies *to* `192.168.1.xxx` that would go nowhere (or rather, towards the ISP instead of the LAN interface) and would prevent the device from establishing a connection.